# Can you pass the type of an object to a function?

Tags: swift

I have an array of differing types of view controllers. I want to be able to check if the array contains various types. 
In other words is there any way of simplifying the following code from

```
for item in theArray
{
   if item is ViewControllerTypeA
   {
     ...
   }
}
for item in theArray
{
   if item is ViewControllerTypeB
   {
     ....
   }
}
for item in theArray
{
   if item is ViewControllerTypeC
   {
     ....
   }
}
```

to something like

```
func doesArrayContainType(T)
{
    for item in theArray
   {
       if item is T
       {
        ....
       }
   }
}
```

Is there any way generics can be used for this? If so how, non of the tutorials or reference on generics are of any help for this particular situation that I can see.

Comment: Yes, you can use `ViewControllerTypeA.self` to get a type object. You can try to use your type for var in the function as `UIViewController.AnyClass`

Comment: This applies to `@objc` objects, not to native swift ones (Try doing this with Int and String and will not compile)

Comment: What to you want to do with the elements in `theArray`? If you simply want to check that it has an instance of `ViewControllerTypeA` in there, you can write `let hasA = theArray.contains { $0 is ViewControllerTypeA }`

Comment: @CodeDifferent I don't want to check the array for a particular object instance of the type, but if it contains an object of that type

Comment: Try the code I gave you. It looks like that you want already.

Comment: @Code Different Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have three different controllers.

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {}
class BViewController: UIViewController {}
class CViewController: UIViewController {}
```

And a function that takes an array of folders and an array of types.

```
func arrayOf<T: UIViewController>(_ array: [T], containsTypes types: [T.Type]) -> Bool {
    return array.contains { vc in types.contains { $0 === type(of: vc) as T.Type } }
}
```

The function checks if the controller's types are contained within the array of types given. If at least one of the types is there, it will return true.

```
let controllers = [
    AViewController(),
    BViewController(),
    CViewController()
]

print(arrayOf(controllers, containsTypes: [ AViewController.self, BViewController.self ]))
print(arrayOf(controllers, containsTypes: [ CViewController.self ]))
```

Comment: `.first(where: ...) != nil` just do `.contains(where: ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass type information to a method

```
extension Sequence {
    // gives you an array of elements that have the specified type
    func filterByType<T>(_ type: T.Type = T.self) -> [T] {
        return flatMap { $0 as? T }
    }
}
```

The above function will give you a list of elements from the target sequence that match the type you want to search for.

You can use it with or without the `type` parameter, provided the compiler can infer the result type:

```
let mixedArray: [Any] = [1, "2", 3, "4"]

// you need to pass the `type` parameter
mixedArray.filterByType(Int.self) // [1, 3]

// you don't need to pass the `type` parameter as the compiler
// can infer T by looking at the sorounding context
let strings: [String] = mixedArray.filterByType() // ["2", "4"]
```